# How to properly filter a wmic diskdrive list

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmic

I'm trying to filter results of a wmic list with `where-object` but unfortunately this does not seems to work.

```
wmic diskdrive list brief  | Where-Object -Property "Caption" -Contains "Samsung"
```

The filtered result is empty, the unfiltered result is as such:

```
Caption                       DeviceID            Model                Partitions  Size

HGST HUH721212ALE600          \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  HGST HUH721212ALE600 1           12000132426240
OCZ-VERTEX3                   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  OCZ-VERTEX3          1           240054796800
Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE5  Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB  4           1000202273280
ST16000NM001G-2KK103          \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE4  ST16000NM001G-2KK103 1           16000900392960
ST6000NM0024-1HT17Z           \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  ST6000NM0024-1HT17Z  1           6001172513280
Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series    \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series    1           512105932800
```

How to filter properly ?

In the end, I want to get the `DeviceID`, eg., `PHYSICALDRIVE5`

Comment: is there a reason NOT to use the built in PoSh cmdlet for this? if not, then try this ... >>> `Get-Disk | Where-Object Manufacturer -Match 'crucial'` <<< for me, that gives the info for my solitary SSD. [*grin*]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WMIC is not a PowerShell cmdlet, and doesn't contain the properties `Where-Object` is looking for.

You can verify this by trying to pipe your command to `Get-Member`.

Using `Select-String` as mentioned in the other answer is a great way to filter any output in PowerShell and is worth remembering.

You could also get the information you are getting from WMIC from a PowerShell cmdlet, and then all the PowerShell filtering and property commands come alive.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object {$_.Caption -like "*samsung*" }
```

Running this on my system with AMD produces:

```
PS C:\Users\ishmael> Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object {$_.Caption -like "*AMD*" }

DeviceID           Caption                                   Partitions Size          Model
--------           -------                                   ---------- ----          -----
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 AMD-RAID Samsung SSD 970 SCSI Disk Device 3          1000202273280 AMD-RAID Samsung SSD 970 SCSI Disk Device
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 AMD-RAID Array 2  SCSI Disk Device        1          999091860480  AMD-RAID Array 2  SCSI Disk Device
```

---

**Command Breakdown**

*Get-CimInstance*

CIM Cmdlets were added as a replacement to the WMI Cmdlets. CIM stands for Common Information Model and is used in this instance to access a standardized set of information about Windows. [DMTF](https://www.dmtf.org/standards/cim) [RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-day-to-day-admin-tasks-wmi-cim-and-pswa/) [MS CimCmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/?view=powershell-7)

*Win32_DiskDrive*

One of the CIM classes that is available to query. There are many CIM classes. Try `Get-CimClass Win32*` to get an idea of the types of CIM classes available that are prefix with Win32.

*|*

Pipe. Sends the output on the left to the command on the right.

*Where-Object*

Where-Object can be used to filter PowerShell output that has been piped to it. To see what kind of objects that can be filtered, pipe your command to `Get-Member` first, which will show you a list of the possible objects.

*{$_.Caption -like "*samsung*"}*

- `$_` is the PowerShell syntax for *self*. Is referring to the piped input.
- `.Caption` the member object of `$_` we would like to query
- `-like` PowerShell comparison operator that allows wildcard patterns [PS Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)
- `"*samsung*"` our search string, the wildcard asterisks are leading and following our string to ensure we match *samsung* anywhere in the output. Leaving out the leading wildcard will show results that only start with *samsung*.

Answer (score 5):

#### I'm trying to filter results of a `wmic` list with `where-object` but this does not work.

> I'm using:
>
> ```
> wmic diskdrive list brief  | Where-Object -Property "Caption" -Contains "Samsung"
> ```

To find the lines containing the string "Samsung" use the following command:

```
wmic diskdrive list brief  | select-string -pattern "Samsung*"
```

With your example it should return:

```
Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE5  Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB  4           1000202273280
Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series    \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series    1           512105932800
```

Answer (score 1):

this does not directly Answer your Question. [*grin*] however, it gives a more "powershell-ish" version of the WMIC.exe call you used.

what it does ...

- sets the target string to filter with
- gets the disk info for all disks
- filters out the unwanted disks
- builds a new object with just the wanted properties
  the WMIC "DeviceID" item seems to map to the ".DiskNumber" property.
- trims away the unwanted "bunch of leading whitespace" in my serial number property
- sends that to a $Var
- displays that on screen

here's the code ...

```
$Maker = 'crucial'

$TargetDiskInfo = Get-Disk |
    Where-Object -Property FriendlyName -Match $Maker |
    Select-Object -Property DiskNumber, Manufacturer, Model,
        # the SN on my ssd has a BUNCH of leading whitespace
        #    the ".Trim()" gets rid of that
        @{n = 'SerialNumber'; e = {$_.SerialNumber.Trim()}}

$TargetDiskInfo
```

the output ...

```
DiskNumber Manufacturer Model            SerialNumber
---------- ------------ -----            ------------
         0 Crucial_     CT1024MX200S     153910A893E4
```